# Join in SQL Server when some query doesn't have results

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with stock product movements (MOVSTOCKS) in two warehouses (CodAlm). For simplify the question, I will focus on a single product (with CodArt = C5):

| CodArt | DescArt | CodAlm | UnidadesStock | EntranStock | SalenStock | FecDoc | TipDoc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 16 | 16 | 0 | 2021-12-31 | IN |
| C5 | Palet | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-12-31 | IN |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 2022-01-11 | SL |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 2022-01-20 | SL |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 2022-02-01 | EN |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 2022-02-14 | SL |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 9 | 9 | 10 | 2022-05-01 | IN |
| C5 | Palet | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-05-01 | IN |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2022-06-10 | SL |

I need to get the stock on a certain day. For this, is necessary obtain stock quantity of the last inventory (TipDoc = IN) and add it purchases quantities (TipDoc = EN) and subtract the sales (TipDoc = SL).

I tried this query:

```
SELECT MV.CODART, MV.DESCART, MV.CODALM, SC.UNIDADESSTOCK + SUM(MV.ENTRANSTOCK) - SUM(MV.SALENSTOCK) as STOCK
FROM MOVSTOCKS MV
JOIN (  SELECT MV1.CODART, MV1.CODALM, MV2.FECDOC, MV1.UNIDADESSTOCK
        FROM MOVSTOCKS MV1
        JOIN ( SELECT CODART, CODALM, MAX(FECDOC) FECDOC
               FROM MOVSTOCKS
               WHERE TIPDOC = 'IN'
               GROUP BY CODART, CODALM) MV2
        ON MV1.CODART = MV2.CODART AND MV1.CODALM = MV2.CODALM AND MV1.FECDOC = MV2.FECDOC
        WHERE MV1.TIPDOC = 'IN' ) SC
ON MV.CODART = SC.CODART AND MV.CODALM = SC.CODALM AND MV.FECDOC > SC.FECDOC
WHERE MV.CODART = 'C5' and MV.FECDOC <= '2022-06-01'
GROUP BY MV.CODART, MV.DESCART, MV.CODALM, SC.UNIDADESSTOCK
ORDER BY MV.CODART, MV.CODALM
```

With above data example and the query I expected to get following results:

| CodArt | DescArt | CodAlm | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 9 |
| C5 | Palet | 2 | 1 |

The problem is that after the last inventory (2022-05-01) there have been no movements and then the join query get 0 rows because the filter MV.FECDOC <= '2022-06-01' in the WHERE doesn't get rows. I could modify the 'ON' condition in the join to MV.FECDOC >= SC.FECDOC and then get at least the inventory row, but I shouldn't do that because on inventory day there might be other previous movements that I shouldn't get for stock calculation.
Moreover, I will have the same problem if I want to get stock in a date for a product without inventory movements, because subquery 'SC' won't get rows.

Any help, please?

Comment: So what is your expected results for the suppliered sample data?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify the result I expect. I have edited the question for include the results that I expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the inventory records exist, but the other transaction records might or might not exist afterwards, you will need to select your inventory records first and then `LEFT JOIN` the other transaction records.

If we only had to select one inventory record, we could start with a `SELECT TOP 1 * ... ORDER BY FECDOC DESC` with appropriate additional conditions. However, to get the latest inventory record for each of multiple warehouses, it get a bit more complicated. Two approaches that come to mind.

One would be to first select distinct warehouse codes (or perhaps distinct warehouse and product codes) and then `CROSS APPLY` a subselect to retrieve the latest inventory record for each.

The other approach would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to number the inventory records by descending date (partitioned by warehouse codes and product codes) and then exclude all but row number = 1.

In either case, the next step would be to `LEFT JOIN` the transaction records, apply a `GROUP BY`, and `SUM()` up the results. Since `SUM()` returns `NULL` if there are no elements to sum, we need to use the `ISNULL()` function to assign a default value of zero.

The following two similar queries demonstrate the above approaches.

```
DECLARE @CODART VARCHAR(10) =  'C5'
DECLARE @AsOfDate DATETIME2 = '2022-06-01'

-- Method 1: SELECT DISTINCT followed by a cross apply
SELECT
    SC.CODART, SC.DESCART, SC.CODALM,
    SC.UNIDADESSTOCK + ISNULL(SUM(MV2.ENTRANSTOCK), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(MV2.SALENSTOCK), 0) as STOCK
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MV.CODART, MV.CODALM
    FROM @MOVSTOCKS MV
    WHERE MV.CODART = @CODART    
) A
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Most recent inventory for each selected CODART, CODALM
    SELECT TOP 1 MV1.*
    FROM @MOVSTOCKS MV1
    WHERE MV1.CODART = A.CODART
    AND MV1.CODALM = A.CODALM
    AND MV1.TIPDOC = 'IN'
    AND MV1.FECDOC <= @AsOfDate
    ORDER BY MV1.FECDOC DESC
) SC
LEFT JOIN @MOVSTOCKS MV2
    ON MV2.CODART = SC.CODART
    AND MV2.CODALM = SC.CODALM
    AND MV2.TIPDOC IN ('EN', 'SL')
    AND MV2.FECDOC > SC.FECDOC
    AND MV2.FECDOC <= @AsOfDate
GROUP BY SC.CODART, SC.DESCART, SC.CODALM, SC.UNIDADESSTOCK
ORDER BY SC.CODART, SC.CODALM
  
-- Method 2: Using the ROW_NUMBER() window function
SELECT
    SC.CODART, SC.DESCART, SC.CODALM,
    SC.UNIDADESSTOCK + ISNULL(SUM(MV2.ENTRANSTOCK), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(MV2.SALENSTOCK), 0) as STOCK
FROM (
    -- Most recent inventory at or before @AsOfDate will have Recency = 1
    SELECT MV1.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODART, CODALM ORDER BY FECDOC DESC) AS Recency
    FROM @MOVSTOCKS MV1
    WHERE MV1.FECDOC <= @AsOfDate
    AND MV1.TIPDOC = 'IN'
) SC
LEFT JOIN @MOVSTOCKS MV2
    ON MV2.CODART = SC.CODART
    AND MV2.CODALM = SC.CODALM
    AND MV2.FECDOC > SC.FECDOC
    AND MV2.FECDOC <= @AsOfDate
    AND MV2.TIPDOC IN ('EN', 'SL')
WHERE SC.Recency = 1
AND SC.CODART = @CODART
GROUP BY SC.CODART, SC.DESCART, SC.CODALM, SC.UNIDADESSTOCK
ORDER BY SC.CODART, SC.CODALM
```

Both queries above produce the desired result. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uMINbAKU) for a working demo.

***** UPDATE ***** To handle cases where we might have transactions (added stock and/or sales) but no prior reference inventory, we will need to assume an initial inventory of zero and include all transactions since the beginning-of-time (start or data). This also requires making the initial `SELECT DISTINCT` the primary source for product and warehouse information. The `CROSS APPLY` becomes an `OUTER APPLY` (similar to a `LEFT JOIN`) and we need to make other adjustments to handle a possible null inventory record. That includes adjusting the date range for the transaction join.

The updated query would be something like:

```
SELECT
    A.CODART, A.DESCART, A.CODALM,
    ISNULL(SC.UNIDADESSTOCK, 0) + ISNULL(SUM(MV2.ENTRANSTOCK), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(MV2.SALENSTOCK), 0) as STOCK
    , SC.UNIDADESSTOCK AS PriorInventory
    , SUM(MV2.ENTRANSTOCK) AS NewStock
    , SUM(MV2.SALENSTOCK) as Sales
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MV.CODART, MV.DESCART, MV.CODALM
    FROM @MOVSTOCKS MV
    WHERE MV.CODART = @CODART    
) A
OUTER APPLY (
    -- Most recent inventory for each selected CODART, CODALM combination
    SELECT TOP 1 MV1.*
    FROM @MOVSTOCKS MV1
    WHERE MV1.CODART = A.CODART
    AND MV1.CODALM = A.CODALM
    AND MV1.TIPDOC = 'IN'
    AND MV1.FECDOC <= @AsOfDate
    ORDER BY MV1.FECDOC DESC
) SC
LEFT JOIN @MOVSTOCKS MV2
    -- Transactions since inventory was last recorded
    ON MV2.CODART = A.CODART
    AND MV2.CODALM = A.CODALM
    AND MV2.TIPDOC IN ('EN', 'SL') -- Alternately <> 'IN' or omitted entirely.
    AND MV2.FECDOC > ISNULL(SC.FECDOC, '1900-01-01')
    AND MV2.FECDOC <= @AsOfDate
GROUP BY A.CODART, A.DESCART, A.CODALM, SC.UNIDADESSTOCK
ORDER BY A.CODART, A.CODALM
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-n1MFf8R) for an updated demo. For this demo, I added a new stock record for warehouse 3 and set the @AsOfDate to '2022-12-31'. I also added details to the result showing the separate initial inventory, new stock, and sales that feed the final STOCK calculation.

| CODART | DESCART | CODALM | STOCK | PriorInventory | NewStock | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C5 | Palet | 1 | 7 | 9 | 0 | 2 |
| C5 | Palet | 2 | 1 | 1 | null | null |
| C5 | Palet | 3 | 6 | null | 6 | 0 |

The above includes cases having inventory with transactions, inventory but no transactions, and transactions with no initial inventory.

I abandoned the `ROW_NUMBER()` alternate approach.

Comment: Hi, this query is great for my first problem: When there aren't movements of stock apart from inventory but with the second problem doesn't works: When inventory record doesn't exists. This assumption is strange but it could happen. Imagine that for the warehouse 2 there wasn't inventory and exist one purchase ('EN') on '2022-05-30' for 6 product units. Your query doesn't get stock for warehouse 2 on '2022-06-01'.

Comment: In that case, we will have to change the `CROSS APPLY` to an `OUTER APPLY` (similar to a  `LEFT JOIN`) and modify the rest of the query to handle a null inventory record. The initial `SELECT DISTINCT` would need to become the primary source for CODART, DESCART, and CODALM. The transaction join date range condition would have to be adjusted to go back to beginning-of-time for the no-inventory case. An `ISNULL()` sould also be needed on the initial inventory value to default it to zero. I'll put something togetehr and post an update.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response, but I had personal problems. Your query is great and it has resolved all my problems!! You are amazing, I haven't words to thank you for your contribution.